# How to remove empty tags AND line breaks with xslt?

Tags: xslt

I want to remove empty tags as well as line breaks from an XML file via XSLT.

**Criteria 1:**
Line breaks should only be removed within text nodes, i.e. the XML should remain indented.

**Criteria 2:**
Should work on any OS.

**Criteria 3:**
If possible there wouldn't be any other changes to the XML.

An example XML would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Container xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <tag1>22</tag1>
    <tag2>33</tag2>
    <tag3/>
    <minimalValue/>
    <maximalValue/>
    <minimalFee/>
    <maximalFee/>
    <tag4>This is text with a
        line break.
    </tag4>
</Container>
```

**The result should be:**

```
<Container xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <tag1>22</tag1>
   <tag2>33</tag2>
   <tag4>This is text with a line break.</tag4>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To omit initial XML declaration you should use `omit-xml-declaration`
attribute in `xsl:output`.

To have indentation use `indent="yes"`.

To remove empty tags, you need a template for **elements** (`match="*"`),
but with a predicate requiring that this element has non-whitespace-only
content (`[normalize-space()]`).
Since there is no template for empty elements, they will not be copied.

To remove line breaks you need a template for `text()` nodes,
copying the normalized content.

So to sum up, you can use the following script, slightly more concise
than the other proposal:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space()]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I added `|@*` in 2 places, to handle attribute nodes,
like in the identity template.
But since your source XML does not containt any attribute nodes,
you could do even without these additions.

Comment: Hey @Valdi_Bo, thanks a lot for your answer. However, I still don't get how it really works. **normalize-space()** is according to the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) kind of a more advanced trimming function which is as I understand applied to the context node when used in a <xsl:value-of ..> tag. You use it however as a predicate in the template. So for the node to be skipped an empty tag must evaluate to false. But what has that to do with "stripping leading and trailing whitespaces and replacing sequences of whitespace characters..".

Comment: @Viktor: The first usage of *normalize-space* is just to normalize "white" charactesrs.
For full description see http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_normalize-space.html
But you can use this function also in the **boolean** context.
Then it answers the question: *Is the normalized string (argument) not empty?*
In other words: *Does it contain something else than "white" chars?*
So, in the predicate I used, it checks just what is to be checked:
*Is the content of the current element not empty?* (whitespace-only content is treated as empty).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The link is useful.

Comment: It actually shows that an empty string evaluates  to a zero-length string which is evaluated as "false" for the predicate. For all other tags it would be true. So eventually one could omit the usage of normalize-space() in the match context and use `match="*[string-length(.) &gt; 0]|@*"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do that. But I've achieved the above with the following template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="child::node()[not(self::text())]|@*">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```